# Fastest way to merge images and convert them to a byte array

Tags: android, image, google-maps, arrays, tile

I'm creating a custom UrlTileProvider for Google Maps API that takes care of the device's resolution :

- if the given tiles are 512x512px, just return the tile
- if the given tiles are 256x256px, merge the four tiles corresponding to the requested tile in the next zoom level to return a 512x512px tile

As the GoogleMaps' TileProvider must be fed with byte[], I need to be able to :

- download an image and convert it to a byte[] - OK
- download four images, merge them into one, and convert it to a byte[] - KO

I have a working solution with Android Bitmaps, but the merging + conversion is really slow (around 1.5 seconds). Here is the code :

```
public class CustomUrlTileProvider implements TileProvider {

    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Private attributes :

    private OnlineMapSource _source;
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Constructor :

    public CustomUrlTileProvider(OnlineMapSource source) {

        this._source = source;
    }

    @Override
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y, int zoom) {

        if(_source.getTileSize().getWidth() == 256 && _source.getTileSize().getHeight() == 256) { return getTileFromNextZoomLevel(x, y, zoom); }
        else if(_source.getTileSize().getWidth() == 512 && _source.getTileSize().getHeight() == 512) { return getTileFromCurrentZoomLevel(x, y, zoom); }
        else return TileProvider.NO_TILE;
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Tile creation :

    public Tile getTileFromNextZoomLevel(int x, int y, int zoom) {

        String topLeftTileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + (zoom + 1)).replace("{x}", "" + (x * 2)).replace("{y}", "" + (y * 2));
        String topRightTileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + (zoom + 1)).replace("{x}", "" + (x * 2 + 1)).replace("{y}", "" + (y * 2));
        String bottomLeftTileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + (zoom + 1)).replace("{x}", "" + (x * 2)).replace("{y}", "" + (y * 2 + 1));
        String bottomRightTileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + (zoom + 1)).replace("{x}", "" + (x * 2 + 1)).replace("{y}", "" + (y * 2 + 1));

        Bitmap topLeftTile = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(topLeftTileUrl);
        Bitmap topRightTile = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(topRightTileUrl);
        Bitmap bottomLeftTile = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(bottomLeftTileUrl);
        Bitmap bottomRightTile = Utils.getBitmapFromURL(bottomRightTileUrl);

        Bitmap[] parts = {
            topLeftTile,
            topRightTile,
            bottomLeftTile,
            bottomRightTile
        };

        Bitmap tileBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(parts[0].getWidth() * 2, parts[0].getHeight() * 2, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tileBitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(parts[i], parts[i].getWidth() * (i % 2), parts[i].getHeight() * (i / 2), paint);
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tileBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

        byte[] tile = stream.toByteArray();

        return tile == null ? TileProvider.NO_TILE : new Tile(_source.getTileSize().getWidth(), _source.getTileSize().getHeight(), tile);
    }

    public Tile getTileFromCurrentZoomLevel(int x, int y, int zoom) {

        String tileUrl = _source.getUrlSchema().replace("{z}", "" + zoom).replace("{x}", "" + x).replace("{y}", "" + y);

        byte[] tile = Utils.getByteArrayFromURL(tileUrl);

        return tile == null ? TileProvider.NO_TILE : new Tile(_source.getTileSize().getWidth(), _source.getTileSize().getHeight(), tile);
    }
    // ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

The Utils.getBitmapFromURL and Utils.getByteArrayFromURL methods :

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        return myBitmap;
    }
    catch (IOException e) { return null; }
}

public static byte[] getByteArrayFromURL(String src) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bais = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream is = null;
    try {

        is = new URL(src).openStream();
        byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096];
        int n;

        while ((n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0) {
            bais.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    finally {
        if (is != null) {
            try { is.close(); }
            catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    return bais.toByteArray();
}
```

So the question is : is there a faster way to achieve the second operations (download 4 images -> merge them -> convert result to byte[]) ? To simplify, is there a way to merge four bye[] (representing images) into one ?

EDIT : I found that what is taking time is not the merging, but the conversion Bitmap -> byte[]. So I'm know trying to use Bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer instead of Bitmap.compress, with no success (no exception but no image displayed). Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that most of the elapsed time is spent retrieving tiles over the network.  If that's so, then any gains in efficiency you might achieve by more efficient code are going to have proportionally small effect.  You cannot speed up the network via your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the elapsed time I gave is the time of the merging + converting. The download time is around 300ms and the merge + convert around 1.5s. I have a better solution for the first operation in pure Java, I will update the original post.